# how can I fix calling this array in the method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
 public int sumgrades(int[] arr_grades)
{
    int sum = 0;


    for(int vals; arr_grades)
    {
        sum += vals;    
    }

    return sum;
}
```

It doesn't like the arr_grades, I have this down at the bottem

```
     LectureEx lect = new LectureEx(); 
    int[] grades = {93, 87, 78, 98, 95, 92}; 

    int sum = lect.sumgrades(grades);
```

any suggestions? I have more code in the program if y'all need to see that too, Thanks!

Comment: What doesn't it like about it? Java is very specific.

Comment: Perhaps the syntax of the `for` loop!

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for a for-each loop is

```
for (int vals : arr_grades)
```

But you have

```
for (int vals ; arr_grades)
```